# VisualSVN Server 3.2 - Unexpected HTTP Status 405

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server on my machine for source control and when I try to access it via the Repo Browser I get the error:

```
 Unexpected HTTP Status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/!/%23WEB/view/head/ProjectA'
 Additional errors: PROPFIND request on '/!/%23WEB/view/head/ProjectA' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed.
```

Accessing it via a browser works just fine.

I installed many times VisualSVN Server and did not have this issue.

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are trying to access repo trough Tortoise using web browser URL.

This thing works fine in browser, but will return 405 in Tortoise:

```
https://path-to-svn-server/!/%23WEB/view/head/ProjectA
```

Try this as repo URL in Tortoise (assuming WEB is repo name, and ProjectA is subfolder):

```
https://path-to-svn-server/svn/WEB/ProjectA
```

Comment: Thank you! In previous versions the browser url and the repo url were the same.

Answer (score 4):

VisualSVN Server 3.2 has [new HTML5-powered web
interface for Subversion repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/).

The URL you see in address bar of a web browser is specific to the new web interface, it has special format and arguments that Subversion clients do not understand. In other words, the URL you see in web browser's address (URL) bar can't be passed to Subversion client as is. If you copy-paste the URL to Subversion client (as you did) you will get `405 Method Not Allowed` error.

To get the URL to paste to a client, you can click on a *"Checkout"* button at the top right corner of the web interface (third from the right), so the URL you should enter in a Subversion client should look like
`https://svn.example.com/svn/MyProject/trunk`.

[image: VisualSVN Server web interface checkout button]